# Wget Directory Options

Tags: wget

I have read the Wget manual, but unfortunately it does not seem to address my issue, so I would be most grateful if someone could offer me a bit of assistance.

We have a website, (say) website.com, which links directly to (say) website.com/1/, website.com/2/, ... etc.

Now each page website.com/r/, where r is an integer, links to a number of pdf documents. Rather than them being located at website.com/r/doc-i.pdf - which would be convenient - they are all located at website.com/files/doc-i.pdf.

Thus, when I run the command `wget -r -l 2 -A pdf website.com`, I will of course end up with a big folder named "files", with all the pdf documents contained within it.

I would much prefer, however, that they be organised into different folders named 1, 2, ..., n, that correspond to the page from which they were downloaded. Since I will be downloading in total around 10,000 pdf files, I would rather not have to do this manually.

So how do I tell Wget to organise the files, not by the website directory structure, but by the route in which it took to get to the file?

I hope my explanation is clear, and that this is not too difficult to achieve.

Comment: There isn't any easy way to do it, as far as I can tell.  You could parse the logs and move the files after the fact, but that wouldn't be robust.  Plus, if you'd try the same operation again at a later time you'd have to download all PDF files from scratch.  It might make sense to do it the other way around: keep the PDFs in the same folder, and add symlinks to classify them.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Ah, well that is unfortunate. I guess I'll have to just do it manually then.

Answer (score 1):

(untested) The following needs some tunning, is just a general idea:

```
### get level1
wget -r -l  website.com/      

#### for each html file otained,
for a in $(find website.com -name '*.html' )
do 
  ### get level 2 but prefix it with the base name
  b=$(basename $a)
  wget -P $b -r -l 1 -A pdf http://$a 
done
```

- probably the find will need some tunnig
- perhaps add something like `mv $b/website.com/files   FINAL/$b` to reduce the levels